# How call another php page after jQuery / Ajax success method?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have following Ajax Success method :

```
 success: function(data, el){

    var parent = el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").parent();

    el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").fadeOut("slow", function(){
    $("<div class=\"jFiler-item-others text-success\"><i class=\"icon-jfi-check-circle\"></i> Success <b class=\"text-danger\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"#delete_upload_image\">Delete</a></b></div>").hide().appendTo(parent).fadeIn("slow");    
    });

    console.log(data);        
 },
```

In this success method you see that I have a link which is :

```
<a href=\"#delete_upload_image\">Delete</a>
```

and

```
console.log(data)
```

This `console.log(data)` is returning following String :

```
mpic_list_573ecaafae8220.41741946 |76|40
```

Now I want call a php page e.g : `delete_upload_image.php` after click on this link `<a href=\"#delete_upload_image\">Delete</a>`  with a string `mpic_list_573ecaafae8220.41741946`  and `76` and `40`

**I mean :**

In `delete_upload_image.php` page I can get 3 string which is passed when I click on the `delete` link.
`

Comment: Can't you just make another ajax request? or a simple GET request to `example.com/delete_upload_image.php?thestring= mpic_list_573ecaafae8220.41741946&firstint=76&secondint=40` ?

Comment: How to get the sting and pass to the Link from console.log() ?

Comment: you can't pass something from `console.log()` just use `data` that variable contains the string you need

Comment: Your want to make a second ajax request for deleting an image ? or just a link GET ?

Comment: I want to call second ajax request to deleting an image which image name is : mpic_list_573ecaafae8220.41741946  and there are 2 id which value is : 76 and 40.

Answer (score 1):

You must either bind the click to a function where you send the user to the desired page or directly make a link in the button.

First, if you want to send the differents params separately, you must split them.

```
var params = data.split('|');
```

And then use it as you want, for example bind the click method to the new link to create a new ajax call.

```
$('#delete_upload_image').on('click', function() {
    var params = data.split('|');
    var url = "delete_upload_image.php?param1=" + params[0] +"&param2=" + params[1] + "&param3=" + params[2];

    // Make AJAX call as you want to url
    $.get(url);

});
```

Comment: I used your given code but why It's not calling Ajax ?

Comment: One question : is there any other way to securely pass those params value ?

Answer (score 0):

Catch your parameters in your data using split method :

```
var stringParam = data.split('|')[0];
var int1Param= data.split('|')[1];
var int2Param= data.split('|')[2];
```

then put your parameters inside your link :

```
$("<div class=\"jFiler-item-others text-success\"><i class=\"icon-jfi-check-circle\"></i> Success <b class=\"text-danger\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"delete_upload_image.php?string="+ stringParam +"&int=" + int1Param + "&secondint=" + int2Param + "\">Delete</a></b></div>").hide().appendTo(parent).fadeIn("slow");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you must put your data in your link tag:

```html
<a href=\"#delete_upload_image\" data-params='" + data + "'>Delete</a>
```

2. then you can send delete requests to "delete_upload_image.php" by below codes:

```js
$(function(){
  $('body').on('click', '[href=#delete_upload_image]', function() {
    var params = $(this).data('params').split('|');
    var url = "delete_upload_image.php?param1=" + params[0] +"&param2=" + params[1] + "&param3=" + params[2];

    // Make AJAX call as you want to url
    $.get(url);
  });      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

now I understand what is your problem;

You want to get the parameters from console.log.

but you can not get the console.log value directly.

What you can do is:

1. hook the console.log function so that you store when it logs by this code:

```js
var store = '';
var oldf = console.log;
console.log = function(){
   store = JSON.stringify(arguments);
   oldf.apply(console, arguments);
}
```

2. use below function to get parameters from console_store variable and delete image:

```js
function delete_image()
{
  var params = store.split('|'),
  queryString = $.param({param0:params[0], param1:params[1], param2:params[2]}),
  url = "delete_upload_image.php?" + queryString;
  $.get(url);
}
```

3. call the function on link click:

```js
$('body').on('click', '[href=#delete_upload_image]', delete_image);
```